# Short story about a girl pursued by a fat man in the hills

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

The viewpoint is from a small girl who is living near to a gas station maybe in the midwest. It's a hot summer and she hears on the radio that there is a another dead child found. She goes to the gas station where a fat man tries to lure her near, but she runs off into some hills, and knows he must not catch her, but he gets closer and closer.

Comment: Hello! Could you add some info about when you read this (year) and where (in a collection, perhaps)? This could help find your short story

Comment: I heard it read in danish in the radio 10+ years ago, but it felt american, and the girl is saved by the pursuers death

Comment: This is annoying because it *feels* familiar. It couldn't be something by Michel Faber could it? Although he has lived all over the place and has a mostly Australian accent he is originally Dutch, so there might be more reason for the radio there to feature him.